# Vuex and vuex getters with arguments

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a small app based on Vue and Vuex. Its just a table with items like that

```
<div class='items'>
  <div v-for='item in items'>
    <span> {{ item.name }} </span>
    <router-link :to='"update/" + item.id'>Edit</router-link>
  </div>
</div>
```

Items array is loaded from Vuex state using getters. So the problem is that when i press the 'edit' button, it redirects me to another page, where i have a function like that

```
computed() {
  item() {
    return this.$store.getters.get_item(this.$route.params.id)
  }
}
```

and generally it should work (i have tested it by passing some numbers instead of "this.$route.params.id") but its not.. why? no errors, nothing, just empty array

my get_item function

```
getters: {
  get_item: (state) => (index) => {
    return state.items.filter((item) => {
      return item.id === index
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you console.log `this.$route.params.id`? make sure you are getting what you expect

Comment: `computed` should be an object, not a function.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining `computed` as a function while it's supposed to be an object. Try instead:

```
computed: {
  item() {
    return this.$store.getters.get_item(this.$route.params.id)
  }
}
```

Comment: You should point out the modification you're suggesting, by explaining it a minimum. Like the comment of Eric Guan :  "`computed` should be an object, not a function."

Comment: @Caillou agreed